# Spyder installed via pip but invisible

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, spyder

I have installed Spyder using pip (after realising that Anaconda gave me issues with my Windows username containing a space).

Pip says it is installed and up to date but if I try to launch it via CMD using "spyder" or "spyder3", cmd does not recognise the command.

I also cannot find it anywhere in the python folder.

This is bizarre, has anyone got any solution?

Thank you

PS I'm running Windows 10 with Python 3.8 and currently use PyCharm

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with pygame and pyinstaller, did you update your paths? Make sure to add C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts

that's where my mine are installed

Comment: Thanks, sorry but I need more detail. What command should I type? I'm not a good at this stuff. Thank you!

Comment: try going to Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings > Under the Advanced tab, select Environment Variables > highlight Path and click edit > Click new and then put the directory path to where the script is located. For me, it was the path I posted in my original reply. After I did that, things worked for me. However, the path to where sypder is on your computer may be different, but none the less, same process, just a different path to add. Also, make sure to change "YourUsername" to whatever your user folder is called lol